# How to log custom flatMap function in Flink (scala) on Kubernetes?

Tags: scala, logging, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm applying a custom flatMap function to a DataStream in Flink and want to log the exceptions, that may occur in my flatMap function. The Flink job is deployed and run on Kubernetes, so I think I can't just write to some log files, and access them manually. I may only have access to the Flink manager through the web browser. So, how can I output the exception to stdout or some error/log stream, such that I can view them through the web interface?

Answer (score 1):

If you change the flatMap to a ProcessFunction, then you could use a [side output](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/dev/stream/side_output.html) to send a report about each exception to whatever sink you want to connect to the side output.